# OpenCMS vfs to rfs not getting updated automatically

Tags: opencms

When i am updating any image from opencms front end vfs(virtual file system), the changes are not getting reflected but when the same file i am updating in the same location in backend rfs(Real File System), the changes get reflected.

```
Moreover if i am putting the file only in backend rfs, the changes do not get reflected until i publish the same from front end.
How to automatically update VFS to RFS in OpenCMS?
```

Answer (score 0):

In a default opencms installation the export in the RFS is on demand.

Look at the **opencms-importexport.xml** file at the line:

```
...
<staticexport enabled="true">       
<staticexporthandler>org.opencms.staticexport.CmsOnDemandStaticExportHandler</staticexporthandler>
...
```